# Can not run python script in VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Yesterday I wrote a short python script in VS Code and ran it successfully. Today I open VS Code but find it I can't run any python script. There is no run button on the top bar. I right click in the empty space, there is no run python option also. How can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: Don't rely on ide's/editors. Terminals are developer's best friend :p

Comment: True. But I just start exploring VS Code -,-

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

The left sidebar should have a little bug icon (for "debug"). Once you click on that, your run button should appear in the top left.

Comment: The run button is grey and it hints "Open a file which can be debugged or run." But I think I already open a python file.